# Can't get Ocean Optics OmniDriver to work

Tags: c++, dll, wrapper, lib, library-path

I'm currently working on a project where I need to be able to communicate with a spectrometer by using Ocean Optics OmniDriver. However, I'm unable to get it to work properly. When I run the debugger in Visual Studio 2017 I get "Frame not in module" and Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

If I run the program without the debugger it runs through the whole program, however I can't use any of OmniDrivers functions...

I think the problems has to do with the libraries, as I can access the function declarations (which are in the included header file, wrapper.h), but I'm unable to locate the the definition of the functions. This causes me to believe that the issue has to do with the libraries.

I would really appreciate all the help I can get and if anyone has experience with OmniDriver it would be great if you could write here so I can get in touch with you.

Cheers, David

Answer (score 1):

After being in contact with a software developer at Ocean Optics, I was told that OmniDriver is not compatible with Visual C++ 2017 which is the reason it didn't work

Comment: I am facing the same problem, were you able to find an alternative to OmniDriver that works with Visual C++ 2017?